# Table in tab view doesn't sit in center in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to build a time-tracking app and I am working on a table for the timesheet. However, the table does not show in the center in the emulator. The reason why I am saying this is because the table shows in the top left of the tab layout instead of the center of the tab when the emulator is run.

here is the Timesheet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Timesheet" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="88dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="Date of Task" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Start of Task" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="End of Task" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Category" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Am I doing something wrong?